# Setting a handler property in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, handler-mappings

In executing the following command with appcmd:

```
set config -section:system.webServer/handlers /"[name='FCGIEcho’,path='*.exe',verb='*']".ResponsebufferLimit:0
```

I get the error message:

```
ERROR ( message:Malformed collection indexer; format is [@position,name='value',
name2='value2',...].  The @position specifier is optional, and [can] be '@start', '@en
d', or '@N' where N is a numeric index into the collection. )
```

I have tried every combination of double/quotes I can think of.

This is a valid property as mentioned here:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/handlers/add#005

I would appreciate help from anyone that understands this syntax.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After consulting the IIS team the answer is here
http://www.coastrd.com/cgioniis7

Comment: Looks like the link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the above link is dead.

Use this:

`appcmd.exe set config /section:handlers"/[name='FCGIEcho'].ResponseBufferLimit:0"`

For site specific changes in config, it'll remove handler module 'WebDAV'

`appcmd set config "sitename" /section:system.webServer/handlers "/-[name=WebDAV]"`